# How can I find a combination of rows from a table where each column sums a specific number (or range)?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have a table with three columns. Let's say the first row is filled with some people names. The second and the third are numbers representing the value they spent. I want to build another table with a subset of those people where the sum from each column of this new table gives a specific value. How can I do that in Python?

Example: This is my table

```
Col1       Col2   Col3
John       10     100
Andrew     5      50
Martha     8      20
Ana        2      5
```

Let's say I wanted a combination where the second column sum is 20 and the third is 125. The result would be:

```
Col1       Col2   Col3
John       10     100
Martha     8      20
Ana        2      5
```

Note: Of course, sometimes might be impossible to get exactly the sum. If the code accepts some approximation, like from 0,9X to 1,1X, being X the sum I want, it would be just fine.
Also, I don't need to get a specific number of rows. It can be a combination of 2, 3,...,n.

Comment: If the required **sum = 10** In, which case, will the rows with `John` & `Martha` and `Ana` will  be acceptable result ?

Comment: @DOOM it would depend on the third column sum. I would pass two arguments, the sum I want for the second column and the sum I want for the third.

Comment: I guess my question is what happends if your condition results in multiple combinations, is that acceptable result.?

Comment: @DOOM There are two reasonable options I guess: 1) both options are presented and the user chooses one 2) any of the options is chosen (it doesn't matter)

Comment: @dekio You could do a `df['Col2'].cumsum()` and `df['Col3'].cumsum()` and then slice the df based on the cumsum value you desire. But this will select the rows in the order of the rows in the df (or can sort the df, but still it will get the subset in the same order of sort).  I guess that is not what you expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the algorithmic task - to find the combination of values that match the needed criteria. For not complex tasks you can use the following script which removes row by row in the dataframe and checks if the column's sum combination matches needed criteria. However, the script should be elaborated in case you want to continue removing rows (i.e. removing two rows if after trying to remove one row the match was not found). Here the specific algorithm should be implemented (i.e. which exact two rows to remove and in which order?) and there could be a very large number of combinations depending on the complexity of your data.

```py
#sample dataframe
d = {'Column1': ["John", "Andrew", "Martha", "Ana"], 'Column2': [10, 5, 8, 2], 'Column3': [100, 50, 20, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#count the sum of each column
totalColumn2 = df['Column2'].sum()
totalColumn3 = df['Column3'].sum()

#function to check if sums of columns match the requrements
def checkRequirements():
  if totalColumn2 == 20 and totalColumn3 == 125:  #vsums of each column
    return True
  else:
    return False

#iterating through dataframe, removing rows and checking the match
ind = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  df1 = df.drop(df.index[ind])
  totalColumn2 = df1['Column2'].sum()
  totalColumn3 = df1['Column3'].sum()
  checkRequirements()
  if checkRequirements() is True:
    print(df1)
    break
  ind = ind+1
```

Comment: Is this removing one row at a time and computing the sum from the rows that are left? This is also removing the rows one by one in order. What if in case if you want to remove rows 2 and 4 to achieve the resultant sum?

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @stanna's solution: We can create all possible combinations of the rows to be dropped using `iterables.combinations()` and check if our requirements are satisfied

```
def checkRequirements(sum1, sum2):
  if sum1 == 20 and sum2 == 125:
    return True
  else:
    return False

# first check if the df as a whole satisfy the requirement
if checkRequirements(df['Col2'].sum(), df['Col3'].sum()) == True:
    print(df)
else:
    # create multiple combination of rows and drop them and check if they satisfy the requriement
    for r in range(1, len(df.index)):
        drop_list = list(combinations(list(df.index), r))
        for idx in drop_list:
            temp_df = df.drop(list(idx))
            if checkRequirements(temp_df['Col2'].sum(), temp_df['Col3'].sum()) == True:
                print(temp_df)
                break
```

Output:

```
     Col1  Col2  Col3
0    John    10   100
2  Martha     8    20
3     Ana     2     5
```

Remove the `break` stmt at the end if you want to print all the matching subsets